# Predicate Logic - Reductio ad Absurdum and Existential Proof.

Tags: logic

### Predicate Logic - Reductio ad Absurdum and Existential Proof.

---

Hey everyone,

I'm new to the math stack exchange - yay first post! - and I have a question regarding reductio ad absurdum and existential proof. So, for my homework I was given this problem:

```
∀xy(Rxy→Ryx), ∀xyz(Rxy&Ryz)
⊢∀xy(Rxy→Rxx)
```

My approach to determining whether the argument above is valid was as follows:

```
1     (1) ∀xy(Rxy→Ryx)            A
2     (2) ∀xyz(Rxy&Ryz)           A
3     (3) ~∀xy(Rxy→Rxx)           A     (for RAA [reductio ad absurdum])
3     (4) ∃xy~(Rxy→Rxx)           3     (QE [quantifier exchange])
3     (5) ∃xy(Rxy&~Rxx)           4     (Ncon [negated conditional])
4     (6) Rab&~Raa                A     (∃proof)
4     (7) Rab                     6     (simp. [simplification])
4     (8) ~Raa                    6     (simp.)
1     (9) Rab→Rba                 1     (∀Ins. [∀instantiation])
1,4   (10) Rba                    7,9   (MP [modus ponens])
2     (11) Rab&Rba→Raa            1     (∀Ins.)
1,4   (12) Rab&Rba                7,10  (conj. [conjunction])
1,2,4 (13) Raa                    11,12 (MP)
1,2,4 (14) ~Raa&Raa               8,13  (conj.)
1,2,4 (15) ∃x(~Rxx&Rxx)           14    (∃xist)
1,2,3 (16) ∃x(~Rxx&Rxx)           5,15  (∃proof discharge 4)
1,2   (17) ∀xy(Rxy→Rxx)           16    (RAA dis. 3)
```

### What now?

So, we can see that we've found the contradiction; however, I know there has to be a better way of solving proofs like these - I always feel a little confused when it comes to using reductio ad absurdum and the existential proof in tandem. I feel like I'm not too sure of  when to discharge these assumptions. If someone could show me a more **efficient** way - show me their take on this argument - likewise, if I've made a **mistake**, please do tell me.

Thanks,
Kyle (Hiefenhoomer)

Comment: Are you sure about (1)? It uses G instead of R...

Comment: Seemingly, the proof can be simplified... From (2) we can have Rxx and thus from it Rxy → Rxx using Conditional Intro.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yeah, sorry about the whole usage of G instead of R - I think I may have hallucinated that character. Also, thanks for telling me to try using a conditional proof, I was just getting so used to using reductio ad absurdum that it was all I used! Much appreciated feedback!